# Text in some apps garbled up with non-Latin fonts after macOS upgrade

Tags: macos, applications, font, settings, ventura

Recently upgrade to macOS Ventura Version 13.3.1. One app in particular (Golden Cheetah) has become unusable because all the text now shows in a non-Latin font.

[image: Screenshot of an app with a different language after macOS upgrade]

The text is unreadable. I have no idea what to do. I also noticed similar garbling of text on a webpage but I don't remember which URL it was.

The primary language of my Mac is English, the region is the United States. When trying to set/check the language of the app in **System Settings** > *App Name* > **Language**, it is set to **System Default - English** and the app "doesn't support additional languages".

Comment: More detail could be added to this question. Such as : (See @Tom 's comment), did this happened already in a previous version of the app? Or in any other app? What is the overall language of your Mac set up to? What is the language the app is set up to (System Settings > [app name] > Language)? etc.

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes I figured that's what is happening. The reason I posted here is to know if there's some known fix to this problem.

Comment: @TomGewecke The same fonts are apparently not "junk" for other apps though? Are you suggesting using only Latin fonts on my computer in order to use an app?

Comment: @TomGewecke I have fonts from several languages, not sure which are "junk." Is there a way to find out?

Comment: You can try opening Character Viewer, selecting a latin character and looking at the Font Variation panel (right lower corner) and see if any font has Devanagari instead of latin.

Comment: @TomGewecke That solved the problem!

Comment: Great!  Suggest you post an answer giving the name of the font causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with [@TomGewecke](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/49804/tom-gewecke)'s suggestion. I first opened Character Viewer (press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Control ^</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> from any input field, choose "Latin", choose a letter like "A" and look for "Font Variation" on the bottom-right-corner) and searched for fonts that were displaying non-Latin symbols for Latin letters. I deactivated them all in the Font Book app.

This solved the problem. I had a few non-Unicode fonts installed and apparently deactivating them fixed it.

Strangely, the problem was only with the Golden Cheetah app.